# Python string function that removes one duplicate pair from multiple duplicates

Tags: python

I'm looking for a string function that removes one duplicate **pair** from multiple duplicates.

What i'd like the function to do:

```
input  = ['a','a','a','b','b','c','d','d','d','d']
output = ['a','c']
```

heres what I have so far:

```
def double(lijst):
    """
    returns all duplicates in the list as a set
    """
    res = set()
    zien = set()
    for x in lijst:
        if x in zien or zien.add(x):
        res.add(x)
    return(res)

def main():
    list_1 = ['a','a','a','b','b','c']
    list_2 = set(list_1)
    print(list_2 - double(list_1))
main()
```

The problem being that it removes all duplicates, and doesn't leave the 'a'. Any ideas how to approach this problem?

For those interested why I need this; I want to track when a levehnstein function is processing vowel steps, if a vowel is being inserted or deleted I want to assign a different value to 'that step' (first I need to tract if a vowel has passed on either side of the matrix before the current step though) hence I need to remove duplicate pairs from a vowel list (as explained in the input output example).

Comment: Why you removed `b`?

Comment: Do you mean remove one duplicate pair? If so, you should update the question to explain that, as of now its not evident how you got output from input.

Comment: Tried updating the question to remove a duplicate pair, apologies!

Comment: What will happen if b exists 4 times?

Comment: if b exist four times it should not give b as a results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These solves your problem. Take a look.

```
lsit  = ['a','a','a','b','b','c']

for i in lsit:
    temp = lsit.count(i)
    if temp%2==0:
        for x in range(temp):
            lsit.remove(i)
    else:
        for x in range(temp-1):
            lsit.remove(i)


 print lsit
```

Output:

```
['a','c']
```

Comment: Welcome, if it helps and answers this particular question, accept the answer for fellow users.

Comment: Actually `if temp>1:` part isn't needed. You can skip it.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through the list. If an element does not exist in the result, add it to the set. Or if there does already have one in the set, cancel out those two element.

The code is simple:

```
def double(l):
"""
returns all duplicates in the list as a set
"""
res = set()
for x in l:
    if x in res:
        res.remove(x)
    else:
        res.add(x)
return res

input  = ['a','a','a','b','b','c','d','d','d','d']
print double(input)
```

Comment: Nice one, but why set is needed? even a list can do that. There is no chance of duplicacy, as you are removing as soon as you are getting a duplicate.